# Return key doesn't work in a UITextField on a UIAlertView .. SIGSEGV

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, uialertview

When I use a `UITextField` in a `UIViewController` I am capable of capture the keyboard event of the return key with `ShouldReturn`:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{       
    this.txtPassword.ShouldReturn = (tf) => 
    {               
        tf.ResignFirstResponder();              
        return true;
    };
}
```

... but when I use an `UIAlertView` I got an SIGSEGV error when trying to use `ShouldReturn`:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{

    base.ViewDidLoad ();            
    loginScreen = new UIAlertView();
    loginScreen.Title = "Login";            
    loginScreen.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.LoginAndPasswordInput;//type login and pass
    loginScreen.AddButton ("Cancel");
    //username
    UITextField usernameField = loginScreen.GetTextField(0);
    usernameField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default;
    usernameField.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next;
    usernameField.ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
    //password
    UITextField passwordField = loginScreen.GetTextField(1);
    passwordField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default;
    passwordField.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next;
    passwordField.ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;

    //(Error SIGSEV happens here!!! and the resignfirstresponder doesn't work)
    passwordField.ShouldReturn = (tf) => 
    {               
        tf.ResignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    } ;
    loginScreen.Show();
```

I don't know what is exactly happening, this is possibly a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: This can happen when the GC has collected the (managed) instance (e.g. passwordField). Now the code you provided looks correct - but maybe something (later) allows `loginScreen` to be disposed (which would allow the text fields to be disposed too). Can you provide a full test case ? You can attach such to a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com Thanks!

Comment: I'm using exactly the same code on MT 5.2.11 with one small difference:  my ShouldReturn looks like this: pwd.ShouldReturn = delegate { passwordField.ResignFirstResponder(); return true; } - so I'm capturing the text field I want to resign and this seems to prevent collection.

Answer (score 0):

Objects created in the scope of ViewDidLoad and which should remain alive (not garbage collected) after the method has executed, must have a reference in the containing class.

```
private UIAlertView _loginScreen; // Declare reference.
private UITextField _usernameField; // Declare reference.
private UITextField _passwordField; // Declare reference.

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();            
    _loginScreen = new UIAlertView(); // Set reference.
    _loginScreen.Title = "Login";            
    _loginScreen.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.LoginAndPasswordInput;
    _loginScreen.AddButton ("Cancel");
    //username
    _usernameField = _loginScreen.GetTextField(0); // Set reference.
    _usernameField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default;
    _usernameField.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next;
    _usernameField.ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
    //password
    _passwordField = _loginScreen.GetTextField(1); // Set reference.
    _passwordField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default;
    _passwordField.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next;
    _passwordField.ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;

    //(Error SIGSEV happens here!!! and the resignfirstresponder doesn't work)
    _passwordField.ShouldReturn = (tf) => // Use reference.
    {
        // This delegate will be executed at a later time, ensure its owner
        // object is rooted with a reference.
        tf.ResignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    } ;
    _loginScreen.Show();
}
```

User *poupou* was of course first to answer this question, but I'd like to put it with sample code since this bug bit me too many times. It's hard to debug and can happen unexpectedly after a garbage collection.

My rule of thumb; whenever `new` or a factory method is used, a reference should be stored, unless the object goes out of scope, or is already nested into another object with reference.

For this reason I prefix fields with an underscore, it signals "this object will live across method scopes in this object, and can be easily distinguished from method variables (the ones without underscore).

Now, it seems that for this case the `GetTextField()` creates a wrapper object and not a reference. Although the `loginScreen` field is rooted, the object returned from `GetTextField()` is not, and prone to garbage collection. I would say it is a bug in the MonoTouch API due to unexpected behavior.

Comment: User asked for UITextView NOT UITextField

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI The SIGSEGV error occurs because of the garbage collected UITextField that is referenced in the ShouldReturn lambda (see tf parameter). This is the question. Nothing to to with UIAlertView specifically. Read before you downvote.